# How do I bulk update Windows 10 build

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch, build

How do I bulk update Windows 10 build (e.g. 1803 to 1809) over the network without data and files being intact.

Comment: Updating from the same to the same version doesn't make sense. It's unclear what you mean by saying that data and files aren't being in tact. If you're talking about a fresh install of Windows, grab a CD/the Windows Media Creation tool.

Comment: The best method to skip several feature updates is to download and mount the ISO for the feature update you want to install.  However, depending on your current build, you might run into some issues doing that.  If you do then the update will be reversed, and you will be notified the update failed, allowing you to download the ISO of the previous feature update and install that instead.  **Without specifics, there is no way to know if you will be able to upgrade from your current build to 1809.**

Comment: Skip 1809 and go to 1903 instead.

Answer (score -1):

Windows Server Ships with a tool called WSUS that hands out updates over a LAN and controls what updates etc… they also have service WDS for pushing full OS images over a LAN.

However, Windows 10 already shares updates over the LAN with one and another.

Regarding “without data and files being intact.” I’m not sure what you mean. If you’re a business always have a backup for user data whenever making any software or OS change.

Comment: Who said it was a server?

Comment: @moab "bulk update Windows 10 build"  "over the network" u would need a server OS for that.